# Python, Selenium can't find input field based with xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I want to enter value 999 in the following inputfield:

```
<input value type="tel" maxlength="3" minlength="0" data-type="change" data-sku="Jopen-Koyt.33_1">
```

I do not want to use the 'data-sku' variable because in that case my code would only work for this specific product, and I want a bot that can automatically order a wide variety of products.

Furthermore, I tried the following xpath.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-type = 'change']").send_keys('999')
```

However I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-type = 'change']").click()` before sending text

Comment: In that case I get the eroror: 
 `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable `.
So I assume it is because my xpath is not selecting the correct input field.

Comment: Check `len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@data-type = 'change']"))`. Is there only one such element?

Comment: Thanks. It shows that the are 2 of these elements. However, `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@data-type = 'change']")[0].click()` once again gives the error: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`. (This is also the case when I select the 2nd element in the list)

Comment: How about `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@data-type = 'change']")[1].send_keys('999')` ?

Comment: Oh thanks. No idea why I didn't try that myself. Thanks a thousand times.

Comment: Since you are accessing last element you can use following xpath. `driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@data-type = 'change'])[last()]").send_keys('999')`

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@data-type = 'change']")[1].send_keys('999')
```